# FTP batch file download multi folders

Tags: batch-file, ftp

How can I download multiple folder from one server to another server via ftp connection. 
My main folder called "backup" have sub-folders called Folder A, Folder B and Folder C. 
My batch file is as below.

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open myserver
myid
mypw
hash
bin

lcd D:\Users\Desktop\test   
#cd smsbackup/ 
cd backup/ #my main folder location
mget *
```

When I run the above script, it show file not found. So, all what I have to do is I have to write script for each folder. It is work when I write it as below.

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open myserver
myid
mypw
hash
bin

lcd D:\Users\Desktop\test   
#cd smsbackup/ 
cd FolderA/ #my main folder location
mget *
```

... and replace with FolderB and FolderC for another scripts.

it is possible to download multiple folders in single batch file? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can first download the list of folders and then in a separate ftp session, iterate over the list.

Run this first ftp script that will download a list of folders

```
open myserver
myid
mypw
cd backup
mls * ls.txt
quit
```

and then dynamically build a second ftp script using the contents of ls.txt, something like this...

```
copy ftp.txt ftp2.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ls.txt) do (
  echo cd %%a >>ftp2.txt
  echo mget * >>ftp2.txt
  echo cd .. >>ftp2.txt
)
```